# Trying to make a Chart using database

Tags: wordpress

So trying to make a chart using database (SQL Queries)

I downloaded this plugin called SQL Charts

I just want a simple chart... i want to show a pie chart with registered users vs a goal amount of registered users.

I dont need it to be sql, just need it to be linked with the amount of registered users

Any ideas?

Comment: how is this related to WP? you want to display number of people who are registered in your WP sites using a chart?

Comment: Hello! Yes, i want to display this in a wordpress site.

Comment: The point is showing the amount of registered users in the site, in a pie chart, comparing it to the "goal"

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to query the database, WordPress has a built in function to get total number of users. You can use `count_users()` like this with a simple chart library like [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/).

If you just need total number of registered users, you can use this:

```
$num_users = count_users();
echo 'Total Number of Users: ' . $num_users['total_users'];
```

`$num_users['total_users']` holds total number of users on the site.

Comment: Thank you for your comments,

 How do I install or integrate Charts.js on wordpress?